# Find all postive $m$ such $\gcd(m,2n!+1)=1,\forall n\in N^{+}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Find all postive integer $m$,such 
>   $$\gcd(m,2n!+1)=1,\forall n\in N^{+}$$

when $n=1$  then we have
$$\gcd(m,3)=1$$

when $n=2$,then we have
$$\gcd(m,5)=1$$
when 
$n=3$,then we have
$$\gcd(m,13)=1$$
when $n=4$, then we have
$$\gcd(m,49)=1$$
$$\gcd(m,241)=1$$
$$\gcd(m,1441)=1$$
I guess the $m=2^a?$ is such it,and other form? in other words,if this answer $2^a$ is only form,How to prove?

Comment: This simplifies to the question : For all primes $p$, does there exist $n$ such that $ p \ |\  2n! + 1$? This is not true for $p=2$, and if  it is not true for any other prime, then $m$ can be composed of powers of that prime as well.

Comment: This looks like the proof of infinite number of primes. I guess then there is no closed form.

Comment: maybe $3^a$ is such it? $n\ge 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note in your question, we must have $\gcd(m,3) = 1$.

If $p > 3$ is prime, let $n = p - 3$. We have 
$$2n! + 1 \equiv -(p-2)! + 1 \equiv (p-1)! + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p},$$
where the last step uses Wilson's theorem.

Thus $\gcd(m,p) = 1$ for all odd primes $p$. Hence $m$ must be a power of $2$.

Conversely, since $2n! + 1$ is odd for all $n$, any power of $2$ answers the question.