# Find the $m$ such $\gcd(m,(n!)^2-4(-1)^n)=1$ for any postive integer $n>2$

Tags: number-theory

let $n\ge 3$ be postive integer,find all postive integer $m$ such
$$\gcd(m,(n!)^2-4(-1)^n)=1$$

$n=3$,then $(n!)^2-4(-1)^n=40=2^3\cdot 5$
then $m$ Prime factor without 
 $2,5$

$n=4$,then $(n!)^2-4(-1)^n=572=2^2*11*13$,
then $m$ Prime factor without 
 $2,11，13$

$n=5$,then $(n!)^2-4(-1)^n=14404=2^2*13*277$,
then $m$ Prime factor without 
 $2,13，277$

$n=6$,then $(n!)^2-4(-1)^n=518396=2^2*19^2*359$,
then $m$ Prime factor without 
 $2,19，359$

$n=7$,then $(n!)^2-4(-1)^n=2^2*17*373553$,
then $m$ Prime factor without 
 $2,17,373553$

I ask$n=8$,then $(n!)^2-4(-1)^n=1625702396=2^2*19*1061*20161$,
then $m$ Prime factor without 
 $2,19,1061,20161$

A similar problem occurred a year ago

[Find all postive $m$ such $\gcd(m,2n!+1)=1,\forall n\in N^{+}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254247/find-all-postive-m-such-gcdm-2n1-1-forall-n-in-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same as your previous question.

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. By Wilson's theorem, we have $(p - 1)! \equiv -1\mod p$.

Now rewrite this as $$-1 \equiv \left(\frac{p - 1}2\right)! \cdot (p - 1) \cdot (p - 2) \cdots (\frac{p + 1}2) \equiv (-1)^\frac{p - 1}2\left(\left(\frac{p - 1}2\right)!\right)^2 \mod p.$$

This then gives $$\left(\left(\frac{p - 3}2\right)!\right)^2 \equiv 4(-1)^{\frac{p - 3}2}\mod p.$$

Therefore your $m$ cannot contain any prime number larger than $7$.

Also, the prime factors $2$ and $5$ are excluded by taking $n = 3$.

So $n$ can only have prime factors $3$ and $7$.

---

On the other hand, one can show that none of the numbers $(n!)^2 - 4(-1)^n$ is divisible by $3$ or $7$ for $n \geq 3$. For $n \geq 7$ this is clear, since $(n!)^2$ is divisible by $3$ and $7$. For $n < 7$ you have already checked them.

Thus the $m$ you are looking are all the numbers of the form $3^\alpha 7^\beta$.

Comment: so $n$ can only have prime factors $3$and $7$,I think is $n$ replace $m$ Thanks,It's nice solution!+1